# How to share common test dependency version in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, build-tools

I'm following this [Gradle User Guid](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html) with `kotlin` DSL, trying to make sub projects to use the dependency version specified in root project. Here is part of the root `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    `java-platform`
}

dependencies {
    constraints {
        api("com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre")
        api("org.testng:testng:6.14.3")
    }
}
```

Here is the `build.gradle.kts` of a sub project:

```
plugins {
    `java-library`
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.testng:testng")
}

val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
    useTestNG()
}
```

When I run `./gradlew run` in the project root directory, it goes fine. However, when I run `./gradlew test` it complains:

```sh
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':misc:java:compileTestJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':misc:java:testCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.testng:testng:.
     Required by:
         project :misc:java
```

I've searched all over the web but with no luck. I guess I should use something like `testapi("org.testng:testng:6.14.3")` in root build script.

Comment: Given that you're using the dependency in the configuration testImplementation, I would rather guess that you should use testImplementation, not testapi.

Comment: @JBNizet that won't work either: "Unresolved reference: testImplementation"

Comment: OK. So I read the manual: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html. The platform project, using the java-platform plugin, allows using two configurations: api and runtime. The project configurations that want to use the constraints defined in the platform project need to depend on that project. So in your case, I guess: testImplementation(platform(rootProject))

Comment: @JBNizet You're right, `implementation(platform(rootProject)) ` works for me. Thanks my friend! Big hug to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in the comments already, you are missing a reference to the platform in your subproject:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform(rootProject)) // Will use the constraints defined in the platform

    testImplementation("org.testng:testng")
}
```

Comment: can you add some more, maybe link for defining such platform